# Apache poi cell style with color and right alignment

Tags: java, apache-poi

Did style cell color && value right alignment like this:

```
 XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(new Color(43,150,150));
 XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = myWorkBook.createCellStyle();
 cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);
 cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
 cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
 //cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

Cell color working but cell value right alignment not working.

Comment: Your described issue is not reproducible without having a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [XSSFCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment align)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#setAlignment-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment-) works in general using the current `apache poi 4.1.1`.

Comment: Only alignment work. But after coloring alignment not works

Comment: I can see horizontal text alignment as 'Right (Indent)' for the cells with the color as specified ( with 4.1.0 ), what do you see & with which version of apache-poi ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is not reproducible. Exact your code snippet works as expected using the current `apache poi 4.1.1`.

Let's have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show that it really works.

Code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

class CreateExcelCellStyleAlingmentAndColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./Excel.xlsx") ) {

   XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(43,150,150), null);
   XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(color);
   cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
   cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);

   XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   XSSFCell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("A1");
   cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

You see, colored and right aligned.